# WPF performance issue when rendering many (32) tables/data at once

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, rendering

Excuse me for posting this seemingly trivial question but I just can't help asking myself how more experienced developers would attack this problem:

My application contains a simultaneous calculation of quite a lot of numbers, after which these numbers are supposed to be displayed in around 32 tables (most of them have around 25 columns and 20 or so rows). After trying to implement these tables with WPF DataGridView I experienced performance problems and was not able to fix them (my problem was a ~30 sec delay of data display due to datagrid rendering). I ended up using Graham Knights [WPF Table View](http://tableview.codeplex.com/) hoping that this would fix my performance issue. The TableView control uses ObservableCollection objects that are bound to its ItemsSource property. I got the binding to work but the delay persists.

I've spent almost two weeks now trying to get rid of this massive and user-unfriendly delay but I seem to get more and more confused and am desperately calling out for some help or useful hints. How would you construct this?

Comment: How do you display 32*25*20 = **16000** cells on the screen at the same time? That's roughly 10x10 pixels per cell on 1920x1080 screen. Do not render controls which the user doesn't actually see. Make sure virtualization is not broken.

Comment: 1. Tables are inside ScrollViewers. 2. The data is not actually displayed at the same time but some of the tables have to be ready for instant display (it's a multi-scenario sort of thing). Thanks for your comment, I will check upon the virtualization. In general, I am wondering how others would construct this. ListView? DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

At this scale, I would try to avoid using any UIElement objects, go down to the lowest level possible: Visual/DrawingVisual/DrawingContext. If this is still not good enough, then write my own rendering routine render into a bitmap and just display the bitmap.